# Jquery Boolean switch not working?

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, boolean, mouse, mousewheel

What I want to do is create a switch that when I mouse wheel up/down, the animation is run(**but will make sure the animation is done first before the second and third...**)

What I did was to set my animation variable to true and run it for the first time and immediately switch it to false.

Somehow the conditional statement doesn't seem to be working.....

My sample code:
http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/veyAc

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
$("#cropInside").mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {

var boxSlide = document.getElementById("whatEver");
var animationStatus = true;

if ([delta > 0] && [animationStatus==true]){
    //code here
    animationStatus=false;
    console.log(animationStatus);
   //call back function after animation complete and set animationStatus=true;
}

if([delta < 0] && [animationStatus==true]){
    //code here
    animationStatus=false;
    console.log(animationStatus);
    //call back function after animation complete and set animationStatus=true;
}

});
```

////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: I noticed you had several unanswered questions and questions without an accepted answer. I enjoyed working on them. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to me that you are wrapping your conditions in an array, effectively making statements like this:

```
if ([true] && [true]) {
if ([false] && [true]) {
if ([true] && [false]) {
if ([false] && [false]) {
```

This is evaluated by converting the array to a Boolean. If you do this: `console.log([delta > 0])` the log will show an array containing a value of `true` or `false`. The contents of the array don't matter when evaluating the array as a Boolean - `console.log(Boolean([]));` will log `true` because the array is true (though empty). This is not a good kind of checking to do and I doubt it was your intention. It seems that when removing the array wrapper from your conditions, they are working properly:

```
if (delta > 0 && animationStatus==true) {
```

Also note that you should avoid `==` in favor of `===` as loose comparison with `==` can also lead to some unexpected behaviors.